# The line between columns is unevenly positioned in the paracol environment

Tags: typography, paracol

I'm typesetting a Roman missal, and I've run into a problem. Consider the following code and its output.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin,slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}

\frenchspacing
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Obhajilni spev}
\end{center}

\kom{Obhajilni spev je bila antifona k psalmu, ki so ga verniki peli med obhajanjem. Mašnik se vrne v sredo in pozdravi vernike:}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Dóminus vobíscum.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Gospod z vami.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Et cum spíritu tuo.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
In s tvojim duhom.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Ite, Missa est.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Pojdite v miru.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Deo grátias.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Bogu hvala.
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the line between the columns is reaching *way* over the top of the text, while staying within its boundries on the bottom. Note that this is a problem which is, as I have observed, unique to the `paracol` environment.

I'd like the "margin" of the line to be customizable and symmetric (a *tiny* overreach might even be aethetically pleasing). How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance and God bless and keep you always. Amen.

Comment: I think to already have warned you about `utf8x` being unmantained and to prefer `utf8`.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the package parskip. It seems to be the parskip from the previous paragraph that "bleed through". I have checked this site for solutions, but found none that works with paracol. You have a very nice package named [multicolrule](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicolrule) that works with multicol and twocolumn mode, but I was not able to convince it to work with paracol.

**Solution 1**

A better solution than the hack described in Solution 2, may be to not using `parskip` at all. Instead, you set `\parindent` to `0pt` and use [etoolbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and the command `\AfterEndEnvironment` to add a vertical skip after the `rightcolumn` environment. This will render at better vertical rule, but you will not be able to tweak it as you ask for. However, to tweak `columnseprule` as you describe, you need to hack the output routine, which is way out of my competence. You may contact the author of [multicolrule](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicolrule) and convince him to make the package compatible with [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin,slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\pagenumbering{gobble}


\newcommand\kom[1]{{\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}

\frenchspacing
\sloppy

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\AfterEndEnvironment{rightcolumn}{\vspace*{6pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Obhajilni spev}
\end{center}

\kom{Obhajilni spev je bila antifona k psalmu, ki so ga verniki peli med obhajanjem. Mašnik se vrne v sredo in pozdravi vernike:}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}
\setlength\columnsep{1em}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Dóminus vobíscum.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Gospod z vami.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Et cum spíritu tuo.}
\end{leftcolumn*}\vspace*{0.25\baselineskip}

\begin{rightcolumn}
In s tvojim duhom.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Ite, Missa est.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Pojdite v miru.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Deo grátias.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Bogu hvala.
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

**Solution 2**

One crude hack is to set `parskip` to `0pt` before you start the `paracol`-environment, and turn on `parskip` after the first (right) paragraph. You also need a `\medskip` before you start the `paracol`-environment. You should reconsider the use of [parskip](https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) if you do not like to do that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper,pagesize,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin,slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[layout=a5paper,vmargin=0.4in,tmargin=0.6in,hmargin=0.4in,paperheight=216mm,paperwidth=154mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand\kom[1]{{\begin{center}\footnotesize \color{red} #1 \end{center}}}

\frenchspacing
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Obhajilni spev}
\end{center}

\kom{Obhajilni spev je bila antifona k psalmu, ki so ga verniki peli med obhajanjem. Mašnik se vrne v sredo in pozdravi vernike:}
\medskip                 % Create some space to the next paragraph 

\setlength{\parskip}{0.0pt}  % Set parskip to zero
\begin{paracol}{2}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Dóminus vobíscum.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Gospod z vami.
\end{rightcolumn}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt}  % Reset parskip

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Et cum spíritu tuo.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
In s tvojim duhom.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
M. Ite, Missa est.
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Pojdite v miru.
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
\textbf{S. Deo grátias.}
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
Bogu hvala.
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```